Can I know in advance the minimum amount required by a node to open a channel?
While experimenting with Lightning Network, I decided to put as little on the wallet as possible. This created problems when creating my own channel - it looks like some nodes have minimum amounts required to open a channel. mempool.space doesn't display this information. Is there a way to know it up-front other than just trying to create it?

The BOLT documents say that its not mandatory to broadcast a minimum channel price, each node do as he want for that, the best way to get this information is to do it by trial and error, try to open a channel with a specific amount and usually they will answer something like insufficient channel size when this amount is not enough.
